# How do I avoid redundancy in query on DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to return only one row per driver on my query.

Currently I am linking my driver table's column `Terminal_number` to my site table's column `First_field_insert`, but within the `first_field_insert` there are some values that are the same! As a result it will produce duplicate returns!

Ideally I would like to only return one row per driver.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT D.DRIVER_ID, D.NAME, D.USER9 AS PHONE, 
       CASE D.TERMINAL_NUMBER WHEN '0' THEN FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY END,
       D.DRIVER_TYPE, S.FAX_PHONE_NUMBER
FROM DRIVER D,
     SITE S
WHERE ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True' 
  AND TERMINAL_NUMBER = FIRST_FIELD_INSERT 
  AND FAX_PHONE_NUMBER = :FAX_PHONE_NUMBER
ORDER BY DRIVER_ID, TERMINAL_NUMBER
WITH UR
```

Comment: Can you add sample table data and expected result?

Comment: Sure so the terminal number for some drivers are 0 (driver table) and some terminals have the same terminal number, as a result whenever i pull the data i get the same driver listed more than once

Comment: Are `first_field_insert` and `first_field_column` two separate columns, or two transliterations of a single column?  We can see `first_field_insert` in the query; the other doesn't appear to be there.  You should really give an outline schema for (the relevant columns of) each table, and some sample data (it needn't be much: 5 rows in each table would likely be sufficient) and the desired output.

Comment: My mistake I meant to write first_field_insert not column

Comment: sure so within the site table the column `first_field_insert` may have two rows that have the same values and as a result when I link it to my driver tables whose column `terminal_number` is the link i return with duplicate results

Comment: This statement would generate a syntax error.  There's also some wacky things - you return `FAX_PHONE_NUMBER` from a table (column reference), but it has to match a parameter (you could just return the constant).  Since it's the only column from your "to many" table, this implies you really want an existence check (`WHERE EXISTS (...`).  Could we get sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(SELECT FAX_PHONE_NUMBER FROM SITE WHERE FIRST_FIELD_INSERT = CAST(TERMINAL_NUMBER AS VARCHAR(2)) AND FAX_PHONE_NUMBER = :FAX_PHONE_NUMBER FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) AS REGION

Comment: Just out of my curiosity, could you please post complete SQL statement? Thanks!

Comment: sELECT D.DRIVER_ID, D.NAME, D.USER9 AS PHONE,  
(SELECT FAX_PHONE_NUMBER FROM SITE WHERE FIRST_FIELD_INSERT = CAST(TERMINAL_NUMBER AS VARCHAR(2)) AND FAX_PHONE_NUMBER = :FAX_PHONE_NUMBER FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) AS REGION
FROM DRIVER D

Answer (score 0):

I like the direction which @Oliver H suggested. Another possibility here is to preselect necessary records in SITE table before joining it with DRIVER table but it certainly not so optimal from performance perspective.

```
SELECT D.DRIVER_ID, D.NAME, D.USER9 AS PHONE, 
       CASE D.TERMINAL_NUMBER WHEN '0' THEN FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY END,
       D.DRIVER_TYPE, S.FAX_PHONE_NUMBER
FROM DRIVER D,
     (select distinct driver_id, first_field_insert, first_field_column, fax_phone_number
        from SITE) S
WHERE ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True' 
  AND TERMINAL_NUMBER = FIRST_FIELD_INSERT 
  AND FAX_PHONE_NUMBER = :FAX_PHONE_NUMBER
ORDER BY DRIVER_ID, TERMINAL_NUMBER
WITH UR
```